# CRTP access to protected CTOR in derived

Tags: c++

I've looked around on stackoverflow, and I don't see my precise issue, so I'm posting it.  I am building this with cxx03, so cxx11+ features are not permitted.

I have the following simplified illustration:

```
template<typename T>
struct unprotect : public T {
    static T *create(void) {
        return new T;
    }
};

template<class T>
struct Base
{
private:
public:    
    static T * Create(void) {
        return unprotect<T>::create();
    }
    static void Destroy(T *p) {
        delete p;
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
protected:
    Derived(void){}
};

int main(int argc,const char** argv)
{
    Derived * d = Derived::Create();

    Derived::Destroy(d);
    return( 0 );
}
```

And this produces the following error in g++ v4.8:

```
24)~/workspace/tricks $ g++ src/tricks.cpp 
src/tricks.cpp: In instantiation of 'static T* unprotect<T>::create() [with T = Derived]':
src/tricks.cpp:14:37:   required from 'static T* Base<T>::Create() [with T = Derived]':
src/tricks.cpp:29:28:   required from here
src/tricks.cpp:24:5: error: 'Derived::Derived()' is protected
     Derived(void){}
     ^
src/tricks.cpp:4:20: error: within this context
         return new T;
```

I would have thought that, since unprotect inherits from T,  the unprotect::create() would have access to the derived class' protected constructor.

And that's the rub, really:  Using CRTP, I want Base to be able to add a create() method that has access to the CTOR for Derived, but **does not require Derived to claim friendship** with Base.

A bad approach would be to do something like the following:

```
template<typename T>
struct unprotect : public T {
    static T *create(void) {
        return new unprotect;
    }
};
```

This would get past the initial problem, but it would balk on (pure) virtuals, and very probably cause a nasty surprise or two.

Is there a way to make the original implementation work?  Again, I **do not** want to add Base friendship to Derived.

Comment: Isn't the usual approach to let `Base` access `Derived` a `static_cast<Derived*>`? You may need kind of injected function pointer operation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in C++ you can't do what you're trying to do. You either have to write the public create function in `Derived` or allow its constructor to be public (what problem are you trying to solve with a protected constructor here?).

All that protected means is that a derived class's `this` pointer can be used to access protected members of the parent class. It *doesn't* grant a child class arbitrary access to arbitrary protected members of arbitrary parent class instances (including when the instance is just created by `new`).

Comment: I can almost agree with that, except that my second version of template unprotect<> works just fine, so it does have that access; otherwise it could not construct itself.

Comment: @zap foster It seems intuitive that `unprotect` can create *itself*.